# Nested SELECT in an INSERT Query

Tags: c#, mysql, subquery

These are my tables:

```
 Equipment
-------------
 ID INT (PKey)
 Name CHAR(10)
 Type CHAR(10)
 LocationID INT (FKey)
 Description TEXT

 Location
-------------
 LocationID INT (PKey)
 Name CHAR(10)
 Code INT
```

The user is given a list of `Location.Code` to select when inputing new `Equipment`. (This is how the user identifies the `Equipment.LocationID`.)

However if I input the data for `Location.Code` as `Equipment.LocationID` it will break the system. Is there  better way of doing this? For example can I come up with a way to select the `Location.LocationID` and use the in place of `Equipment.LocationID`?

**NOTE** I can't change what the user selects, that has to remain the same.

For example (pseudo code):

```
string userInput = "110"; // Location.Code
SELECT LocationID FROM Location WHERE Code = @userInput;

userInput = LocationID; // LocationID = 1;
INSERT INTO Equipment(LocationID) VALUES (@userInput);
```

Is this the best way or is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merge two queries into one as below

```
INSERT INTO Equipment(LocationID) SELECT LocationID FROM Location WHERE Code = '110';
```

Comment: Is that `INSERT INTO Equipment(LocationID) VALUES (SELECT LocationID FROM Location WHERE Code = '110');`?

Comment: Yes, both are valid query.

Comment: I tried this while inserting multiple fields and just encased this in brackets and it works perfectly. Thanks so much!